# how spark load files from HDFS and how it is related to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

How spark laod data from HDFS in cluster?
How the blocks are converted into RDD?

Lets say I have 3 node cluster and I have file called log.txt which is divided into  3 blocks. All the 3 node have one each block.

How spark load the log.txt and how it will be converted into RDD?

Comment: There are nsny to google explanations for this already

Comment: Your file is only split to at least 3 blocks if it is 3x larger than the block size.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is no different than any HDFS client.

The namenode is contacted for a file, it returns the locations of the blocks, then the HDFS client will fetch the blocks from the datanodes.

Blocks are not "converted into" an RDD, rather the RDD is just metadata applied over the Hadoop `InputSplit`s that are formed from the `InputFormat` of the `RecordReader`. RDDs are lazily evaluated, so therefore they don't represent a transfer or conversion of data